# How to know if a node exists in xml with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how to know in an xml column if there is a node with a specific name.

For example:

My XML:

```
<Parent>
  <nodes>
    <Component1>      
    </Component1>
    <Component2>      
    </Component2>
  </nodes>
</Parent>
```

I would like to know if there is a Component2 node.

```
  SELECT T.key
  FROM [Tabletest] as T
  WHERE T.LastUpdate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) 
  AND T.xmlColumn.Value.exists('/Parent/nodes/@Name eq "Component2"') = 1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Doesn't `WHERE T.xmlColumn.exist('/Parent/nodes/Component2') = 1` work?

Comment: Great thanks, it was so easy.....

Comment: FYI, `@Name` is for an node *attribute*. Example `WHERE T.xmlColumn.exist('/Parent/nodes/Component3[@Name = "ABC"]') = 1` would find `<Component3 Name="ABC"></Component3>`